# Mongoid / Rails : Find Questions where User.id does not appear in referenced Answer collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

The title is the problem in a nutshell. Here are the simplified models I am using :

```
class Test
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  embeds_many :questions
  attr_accessible :name, :questions      
end

class Question
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :text, :type => String

  embedded_in :test
  has_many :answers
  attr_accessible :text, :test, answers    
end

class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :value, :type => Integer

  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :value, :question, :user      
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :answers
  attr_accessible :answers    
end
```

I want to be able to retrieve all the unanswered questions in a test for a user with the minimal amount of database queries.

This is the best solution I have thought up so far

```
answered = []
user.answers.each {|a| answered << a.question_id}
test.questions.where(:_id.nin => answered).length
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Questions are embedded in Test, Answers are referenced in Question. Test would make the query and return the results, so it has access to the embedded Questions.

Comment: oh I see now, you mean you need all test.questions that are NOT answered by the user. I thought questions were asked by users and you want unanswered ones. fooled by SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: 
you need to query for the non-existence of a constrained select:

```
test.questions.find_by_sql("WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM answers WHERE answers.question_id = questions.id AND answers.user_id = #{user.id}")
```

or count 0 of a conditional join

```
test.questions.joins("INNER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id AND answers.user_id = #{user.id} AS user_answers").where('COUNT(user_answers.id) = 0')
```

let me know if these work. any insight on their performance?

**ORIGINAL ANSWER, INCORRECT** cos it was assuming we need totally unanswered questions ASKED by the user:

use a counter cache on answers. This assumes an answers_count integer column on the questions db table.

```
class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :value, :type => Integer

  belongs_to :question, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :value, :question, :user      
end
```

Given this, your query can be:

```
test.questions.where(answers_count: 0, user_id: user)
```